# Why is onActivityResult intent data is null?

Tags: java, android, null

This is driving me absolutely crazy. Can anyone point out my mistake. When the activity result returns, the intent data is always null.

```
public void btnAddActionOnClick (View v) {
Intent i = new Intent(NFCEditActivity.this, NFCAddActionActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
this.startActivityForResult(i,1);
return; 
}
```

...

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {      super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

  if(data==null) { Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Intent bundle extras 'data' is null!"); return ; }
      ...
  }
```

...

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,   long arg3) {
        selectedAction = (Action) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("action", selectedAction.intActionNumber);
            data.putExtra("test", "test");
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

        finish();
        return;
    }  
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're sending the wrong Intent.  Shouldn't it be `setResult(RESULT_OK, data)`, not `setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)` ?

Comment: setResult(RESULT_OK, data);

I've rewritten it so many times I'd missed that. Fixed the code with the same result. Other ideas?

    08-09 16:59:47.683: E/RTA(5757): Intent bundle extras 'data' is null!
    08-09 16:59:47.683: E/RTA(5757): onResume

Comment: Anyone have any advice on this?

Comment: I'm to the point now where I might just as well implement my own data transfer mechanism using onResume and sharedPrefs.